# How can I get past login and password request?

Tags: login, tty

I updated my Ubuntu to 15.10 (Wily werewolf).

Presently, the screen shows:

```
Ubuntu 15.10 Karaktah7 ttyl

Karaktah7 login:_
```

I set up the name of the computer as Karaktah7. But how can I can get in?

Comment: Did you set a password when you installed? Have you tried simply pressing 'Enter'?

Comment: I did, it reproduced what I put up in the original question a second time!

Comment: What do you mean by updated? Installed from scratch? Upgraded? In the first case, you have had to set up new credentials. In the second case, your credentials remain in place. Also, you can try GUI login, using CTRL+ALT+F7

Comment: It was an update, the system came preinstalled with 14.04 I believe. Will try the GUI login!

Comment: No response, insertion point just keeps blinking!

Answer (score 3):

You enter your **user name** to the `login:` prompt and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then it will ask for your `Password:` and you enter that **password**. Confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.
Note that the password input is silent, that means no characters (not even `*`) will be displayed while you type.

---

Now you have a console login. It's simply a terminal, no GUI.
As that's probably not what you want, you now have the chance to investigate the cause of your problem why the GUI login screen (lightdm) does not show up.

A good way to start would probably be to run `sudo systemctl start graphical.target` (command to load the full GUI including login screen for releases using `systemd`) and observe whether it outputs any error messages.

Comment: I've done those but I get a reply of login incorrect. I am not really sure I set up a username; I remember during the set up process for this system, I was required to enter a name for the computer when talking to other computers and for itself as well as a password but I don't remember a username request. Also, this is my first experience with UBUNTU, maybe I missed something?

Comment: You were asked for a hostname, username and password on the same dialogue window: [example image](http://news.softpedia.com/images/extra/LINUX/large/ubuntu1010installation-large_008.jpg)

Comment: Yes I do remember the (example image). Is there anyway I can reset the system or retrieve these details? Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: You can boot to a recovery mode root shell without entering a password by following the steps described [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/367990). Follow the first answer to reset your password. You will find out the name of the user you created during the installation with the command `getent passwd 1000 | cut -d: -f1`. Run it after the `mount` and before the `passwd` command described in the linked guide.

Comment: Okay, so I read most of what was written in the link you gave, held down shift since it's a single boot system  and a page showed up having on its list Advanced options for Ubuntu. I clicked on that, and saw a second menu with the kinda stuff mentioned on the link you gave but instead of recovery, it was given as safe mode. I still selected that and it ran through some command instructions and the stopped on the page  I have been seeing from the get go only the insertion point was at the beginning of Karaktah7 login: I'm stuck! Sos!!!

Comment: Nobody describes encountering safe mode only recovery mode!

Comment: I guess "safe mode" or "recovery mode" is the same and just a translation difference. However, I don't really understand how you proceeded. You should get a menu where you can select `root - drop to a root shell` or similar. This should take you to a command prompt looking like `root@computername:~#`, not to a login screen. Please clarify, you can upload screenshots to https://imgur.com and add the links here if needed.